# Qt on Ruby cannot import any images / icons?

Tags: ruby, qt

I using Ruby with Qt4. Everything works great except loading images from files. I tried load them using resource files included to the .ui file. Without any result. I tried also in the code. In this way for example:

```
class Window < Qt::Window
  def initialize
    filename = "images/icon.ico"
    icon = Qt::Icon.new filename
    setWindowIcon icon
    puts File.exist? filename
    puts Qt::File.new(filename).exists
    puts !icon.isNull
    puts icon.name
  end
end
```

Icon still empty. Result looks like:

```
true
true
true
<empty line>
```

When I try to load image as QPixmap and resize them I got error with information: "empty QPixmap cannot be resized".
Image is in relative location from script in 'images/icon.ico', but I tried to use absolute path (e.g. E:/Ruby/Project/images/icon.ico). The result was the same. I working under Windows but paths works outside Qt. For example with Yaml files. Loading files .ui works perfectly. Where is the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

I already found details about this problem. Problem is with loading plugins libraries .DLL, on all of languages used Qt (I think so).

1. Copy files (e.g. qico4.dll, qjpeg4.dll) from **[QtBin]/plugins/imageformats/**. to directory near our project with similiar path structure. For example **[OurProject]/foobar/imageformats/**.
2. Next need to use **QApplication::addLibraryPath(String)** to add our new plugins path. I did example in Ruby:

   ```
   class App < Qt::Application
     def initialize
       super ARGV
       addLibraryPath 'foobar' # There is qico4.dll
       icon = Qt::Icon.new 'images/icon.ico' # Now I can use .ico!
       setWindowIcon icon
       # ... show windows et cetera.
     end
   end
   App.new.exec # All of windows now have icon from icon.ico.
   ```